# Mysql crash when importing sql file into mysql Database

Tags: mysql

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 Linux system with following configuration. 16GB Ram and 1 TB mountable hard-disk for storing data in to GB. I have uploaded some of databases around 100 GB in MySQL 8.0.25 and when I am trying to upload another 200 MB SQL file after restarting server. I have also monitoring process and swap and core utilisation which is normal and I am getting below error. When try to restart MySQL then I m not able to start and following are the MySQL logs file which I can not able understanding the problem. As I have set below configuration in `mysqld.conf` in `/etc/mysql/mysqld.conf.d/mysqld.conf` file. What should I do that below MySQL error will not come?

Mysql Logs

```
The manual page at HTTP://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains**
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
"2021-07-18T06:52:16.708842Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 
8.0.25-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) starting as process 2762
2021-07-18T06:52:16.717495Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has 
started.
2021-07-18T06:52:23.576990Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-013183] [InnoDB] Assertion failure: 
trx0rec.cc:579:undo_rec_flags == 0x00 thread 140373453129472
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
06:52:23 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
Most likely, you have hit a bug, but this error can also be caused by malfunctioning 
hardware.
Thread pointer: 0x55e6b0509d80
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 7fab3dcf3d20 thread_stack 0x46000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace(unsigned char const*, unsigned long)+0x41) 
 [0x55e6aaa6b681]
 /usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x31b) [0x55e6a98bbf6b]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x153c0) [0x7fab4a3553c0]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0xcb) [0x7fab499b218b]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x12b) [0x7fab49991859]
 /usr/sbin/mysqld(+0xea257e) [0x55e6a95e557e]
 /usr/sbin/mysqld(trx_undo_rec_get_pars(unsigned char*, unsigned long*, unsigned 
 long*, bool*, unsigned long*, unsigned long*, type_cmpl_t&)+0x178) [0x55e6aad5cad8]
 /usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x263daff) [0x55e6aad80aff]
 /usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x26414f7) [0x55e6aad844f7]
 /usr/sbin/mysqld(trx_lists_init_at_db_start()+0x174) [0x55e6aad84d14]
 /usr/sbin/mysqld(trx_sys_init_at_db_start()+0x275) [0x55e6aad74715]
 /usr/sbin/mysqld(srv_start(bool)+0x3e0c) [0x55e6aad3340c]
 /usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x2428a9f) [0x55e6aab6ba9f]
 /usr/sbin/mysqld(dd::bootstrap::DDSE_dict_init(THD*, dict_init_mode_t, unsigned 
 int)+0x9e) [0x55e6aa7fa17e]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(dd::upgrade_57::do_pre_checks_and_initialize_dd(THD*)+0x1a9) 
[0x55e6aaa3e8a9]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x1234016) [0x55e6a9977016]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x28dfefa) [0x55e6ab022efa]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x9609) [0x7fab4a349609]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x43) [0x7fab49a8e293]

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (0): Connection ID (thread ID): 1
Status: NOT_KILLED"**
```

What I'm doing wrong? I have tried with small size of sql file import and getting same error in MySQL 8.0.25

Comment: Please, do this: " Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.".

Comment: Not a programming question. You could try asking on [dba.se]

Comment: There are many ways to "upload".  Please show us the specific commands and/or SQL used.

Answer (score 0):

## 1. did you execute DDL sql, before restarting?

there is `do_pre_checks_and_initialize_dd` in crash log, which means Mysql is doing instance recovery.

## 2. hope you could post the first crash log

## 3. `trx_undo_rec_get_pars` may have some wrong in instance recovery

### basing on the current crash log

> https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8.0/storage/innobase/trx/trx0rec.cc#L549